# Placing openlayers marker using variables in fromLonLat() (node js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, openlayers

So im creating an app that shows the current location of different coordinates that should be shown in the map using markers, however, the marker does not show in the correct location as shown in the picture [Markers pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPWUe.png), where it should be 5 markers at different locations.

Here is the code for displaying the markers:

```
 for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
          console.log(typeof (coord[i]));

          var element = document.createElement('div');
          element.innerHTML = '<img src="https://cdn.mapmarker.io/api/v1/fa/stack?size=50&color=DC4C3F&icon=fa-microchip&hoffset=1" />';
          var marker = new Overlay({
              position: fromLonLat([coord[i]], 'EPSG:3857') ,
              positioning: 'center-center',
              element: element,
              stopEvent: false
          });
          map.addOverlay(marker);
        }
```

The coord array contains arrays of coordinates ex. [16.3725, 48.208889]
Note that it is working properly when the coordinates are inputted directly in the "fromLonLat" instead of a variable.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You can check where/how the coordinates are being written. One classical issue is having an app running with a locale whose the decimal separator is a comma. The coordinate in the DB looks fine, it is written with a comma (123,4) and OL reads it and completely destructs it (either with very wrong values, or it fails and no point is loaded) If you try by hand, you would use a dot instead of a comma and everything works well

Answer (score 0):

If `coord` is an array of coordinates, the problem is that instead of passing the coordinate, `coord[i]`, you are passing an array of coordinates, `[coord[i]]`. The function take a coordinate as a parameter [OL API - fromLonLat](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_proj.html#.fromLonLat).

BTW, `EPSG:3857` is the default so no need to pass it as a parameter.

*UPDATE: changes to the code provided in comments*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Overlay from 'ol/Overlay';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import Tile from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import Feature from 'ol/Feature';
import Point from 'ol/geom/Point';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector';
import Style from 'ol/style/Style';
import Icon from 'ol/style/Icon';
import {fromLonLat} from 'ol/proj';
import {transform} from 'ol/proj';
import{DB_CONFIG} from './Config';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/database';

class Map2 extends Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);        
        this.mapRef = null;
        this.setMapRef = element => {
            this.mapRef = element;
        }
        this.Longitude = props.Longitude;
        this.Latitude = props.Latitude;
        this.RFID = props.RFID;
        this.Name = props.Name;
        this.passengerID = props.passengerID;
        const {Name,RFID,Longitude,Latitude} = this.props;
        this.map = null; // <- keep a reference to the map
        this.vectorSource = null; // <- keep a reference to the source
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const mapDOMNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.mapRef);
        this.vectorSource = new VectorSource();
        // Custom image for marker
        let iconStyle = new Style({
            image: new Icon({
                anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
                anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
                src: 'https://pngimg.com/uploads/gps/gps_PNG54.png',
                scale: 0.15
            })
        });  
        let vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
            source: this.vectorSource,
            style: iconStyle,
            updateWhileAnimating: true,
            updateWhileInteracting: true,
        });
        // Create our initial map view
        let mapCenter = fromLonLat([ -74.0446426, 40.6892534 ]);
        let view = new View({
            center: mapCenter,
            zoom: 10
        });
        this.map = new Map({
            target: mapDOMNode,
            view: view,
            layers: [
                new Tile({
                    source: new OSM(),
                }),
                vectorLayer,
            ],
            loadTilesWhileAnimating: true,
        });
        // get data from firebase
        firebase.database().ref().child("Passengers").orderByChild("Name")
        .on("value",snapshot => {
            if (snapshot.exists() && Name && Longitude && Latitude)){
                const iconFeature = new Feature({
                    type: 'click',
                    geometry: new Point(
                        transform([Longitude, Latitude], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
                    )
                });
                this.vectorSource.addFeature(iconFeature);
            }
        });
    };

    render() {
        const styles = { height: '100%', width: '100%'}
        return(
            <div style={styles} ref={this.setMapRef}></div>
        );
    }
}

export default Map2
```

Comment: Yes it contains multiple arrays ex. coord[0] = [123, 456]
coord[1] = [567, 890] and so on, or am i getting it wrong? Edit: if i pass it as coord[i] without the brackets, it does not accept it.

Comment: That's weird, what exactly is the problem? .. Can you add the value of `coord` show by `console.log`

Comment: Here is the log for cord (https://i.imgur.com/YRBbGYV.png), dont worry about cord[0] since I don't start from index 0.
On a side note, if I try to use fromLonLat(cord[1]) (without the brackets), it states that the coordinate is undefined.

Comment: And lastly, if I also use a condition in the for loop with an external variable, i < coord.count, the loop does not seem to work so for now I'm using a constant.

Comment: In the log you have 2 coordinates, but you are iterating 2 more times, that is a problem. The correct loop should be  `for (let i = 1; i < coord.length; i++)`. I think you might have a problem with the variable context, please add where are you defining the variable and where is the code you are showing.

Comment: I'm also not sure where to place the variable declaration for the coord array. It's declared outside the class. And then I fill it with the components with a function in ComponentDidMount() before and now am trying it in the constructor (https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArBHaZP1appfqCUyCVjldAFqMOPE?e=WKy2hH)

Comment: I did some basic changes to your code, take a look at the updated answer. The most relevant change it to add `coords` as a property of the component, I think that is the correct way. I also keep a reference to the `map` as property, you might need to use it later. I would strongly recommend to use a linting tool, it will make your code much better.

Comment: Thanks for the help in tidying the code. Unfortunately, the markers still don't show up. But still, the array contains the right values of the coordinates to be shown when logged.

Comment: There is one important issue that I am not sure it's ok in the code .. The firebase request is async, right?, so I am not sure the coords are loaded when you are creating the features .. Can you confirm that the `console.log(coord)` in the `for` when the features are created is actually good?

Comment: Yes it actually logs but I don't think that it is loaded before the features are created that's why the markers are not showing and why the for loop also does not work if I use the coord.length in the for loop's condition. Any idea where and when am i supposed to put the values into coord so that it'll load before the features?

Comment: I thought so, in that case you need to create the features after you get the data from firebase. I am not sure what is you data structure, but I have updated the answer, it might guide you. You will see I remove `coords` variable, because you don't need it now, you can retrieve the features from the source. Check that when data is retrieve from firebase, then the feature is created an add it to the source.

Comment: Thanks, will try that. Pardon for the extended discussion as I cannot chat yet because of my rep.

Comment: Unfortunately it still does not work and when I try to log the Long and Lat in the process of showing the markers, nothing shows up.

Comment: Add a log right after adding a feature to the source, something like this `console.log(this.vectorSource.getFeatures());`. Let me know the result.

Comment: It outputs 2 times at the end and I expanded the last output (https://i.imgur.com/i4uF8kQ.png), also note that I made the vectorsource a state variable since it states that vectorsource is undefined in componentDidMount.

Comment: We need to check the longitud and latitude values of the geometries of the features are OK, the other things of the feature seems fine. You are right I miss `this` when initializing the source in `componentDidMount` method. Check if geometry is OK, and let me know.

Comment: These show up when i expand the values section (https://i.imgur.com/iCUowp7.png)

Comment: It looks fine, what is actually happening now, marks are showing in the map?

Comment: I miss another `this` for the `vectorSource` when creating `vectorLayer`, check the updates in the code, it should work like that, you have already check that the features are in the source, with the fix I add the correct source is in the layer and the layer in the map.

Comment: I tried the updated code and the markers still don't show up... I tried substituting a number itself inside the transform and the marker doesn't show. However, when the firebase part is deleted (which loads the Long and Lat values from firebase) and a number is inputted in the transform, it shows up. And also , there's an extra closing parenthesis in the "if (snapshot.exists() && Name && Longitude && Latitude))" .